# Using slice notation to set 1 dimension of numpy array

Tags: python, slice

From what I understand of python's slice notation, using the slice notation shallow-copies the array in question.

However, what happens if you set a slice of an array equal to a certain value?

For example:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.zeros(shape=(3,2))
b=np.zeros(shape=(3,2))

for i in range(0,2):
    a[:,i]=i+1

for i in range(0,2):
    for x in range(0,3):
        b[x,i]=i+1

print a
print b
```

Here a and b are identical.

Is there a reason I should not use the slice notation in this way? (I have never seen anyone use the slice notation in this way, so I feel like there might be)

Comment: Why not use the efficient numpy [iterator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html)?

Comment: I appreciate that there are other ways of doing this - however that's not my question. I'd like to know why using the slice notation works, and whether/why I should avoid using this.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "I feel like there might be" because slicing is usually faster, easily readable and saves code

Comment: I've never seen anyone use slice notation in this way (i.e. I've only ever seen people use b=a[:,i] not a[:,i]=b), which I why I am unsure if this is an acceptable way to use slice notation

Comment: It would be more efficient to just do `a[:] = tf.arange(1, 3)[np.newaxis]`.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason you cannot use your code. below is a speed test of the sample above expanded a bit to ensure that it would take enough time to register.

## test of numpy code on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_python_ide.php

```
import numpy as np
import time

a=np.zeros(shape=(4,3))
b=np.zeros(shape=(4,3))

print "--before--"
print a
print ""
print b

start_time = time.time()
for i in range(0,3):
    a[:,i]=i+1

time1 = time.time()

for i in range(0,3):
    for x in range(0,4):
        b[x,i]=i+1

time2 = time.time()
print "--after--"
print a
print ("this took %s seconds\n"% (time1-start_time))
print b
print ("this took %s seconds\n"% (time2-time1))
print "--done--\n"
```

## ----- output ----

```
    --before--                                                                                                                                             
[[ 0.  0.  0.]                                                                                                                                         
 [ 0.  0.  0.]                                                                                                                                         
 [ 0.  0.  0.]                                                                                                                                         
 [ 0.  0.  0.]]                                                                                                                                        

[[ 0.  0.  0.]                                                                                                                                         
 [ 0.  0.  0.]                                                                                                                                         
 [ 0.  0.  0.]                                                                                                                                         
 [ 0.  0.  0.]]                                                                                                                                        
--after--                                                                                                                                              
[[ 1.  2.  3.]                                                                                                                                         
 [ 1.  2.  3.]                                                                                                                                         
 [ 1.  2.  3.]                                                                                                                                         
 [ 1.  2.  3.]]                                                                                                                                        
this took 1.21593475342e-05 seconds                                                                                                                    

[[ 1.  2.  3.]                                                                                                                                         
 [ 1.  2.  3.]                                                                                                                                         
 [ 1.  2.  3.]                                                                                                                                         
 [ 1.  2.  3.]]                                                                                                                                        
this took 7.86781311035e-06 seconds                                                                                                                    

--done--
```